# how to rebuild android apk file - react-native

Tags: react-native, apk

I am developing an android app using react-native framework. I already generated apk file for that app but now i have done some changes to my app i mean in code i have added some functionalities. so how can i rebuild apk file that whatever changes have done should reflect to apk file. i have generated apk file by following the guidelines given in react-native documentation.

I also tried for another app like deleting existing apk file and tried to build another apk file but it could not happen.

Comment: Just run the command again or am I missing something  ? Are you facing any problems ?

Comment: Key pair not generated, alias <my-key-alias> already exists

Comment: this is the error i am getting

Comment: Key generation is one time process. You don't know need to regenerate it every time you rebuild the apk.  Just run the `gradlew assembleRelease` command

Comment: i just need to type gradlew assembleRelease in cmd prompt ?

Comment: Yes. That should be enough provided

Comment: thank you @agent_hunt... its working

Answer (score 3):

**

> For reactNative 0.6 or higher version:

**

*Step-1:*

**First navigate to your project folder in command line (For windows command prompt or git bash)**

*Step-2:*

> Run one after another the following commands

`$ cd Android`

`$ ./gradlew clean`

`$ ./gradlew cleanBuildCache`

`$ ./gradlew bundleRelease`

`$ cd ..`

`$ react-native run-android --variant=release`

> It should rebuild your project app

Happy coding!